# How costly is it to unregister a listener (in terms of battery life)?

Tags: java, android, accelerometer, sensors

I'm collecting acceleration data and I only want about 250 samples of data every 10 seconds (scheduled with a timer). 250 samples is usually done in about 5 seconds or so and then I process the data and store it. When I have collected 250 samples, I unregister the listener. Then when the whole ten seconds is up, the task tells the program to register the listener again and collect 250 samples all over again. Is this efficient? Or would it be better just to put a boolean check to stop collecting data after 250 samples, leaving the listener on?

Comment: I would test both scenarios for a couple of hours and see which one drains the battery more :).

Comment: @MihaiClaudiuToader By simply calling the unregister method you could save a couple of wasted hours for yourself :)

Comment: @Anton if you are sure that it works like that then sure do it. But the requester doesn't know it and he was looking for an answer. I thought it would be good to give him a way of figuring it out himself :).

Answer (score 2):

Registering and unregistering would be better. Listening to sensor drains battery and you are talking about ignoring 250 samples every 10 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

You should only register listener when you definitely need the data, and unregister as quick as possible. That's because while you don't listen to accelerometer it's in idle or off state with minimal effect on battery. But when you do acquire data from it, the sensor is on and works in full power